# Filter rows based on comma-separated string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a set of ids as a comma separated string like '2461519,2461520,2461521'. I need to pull all the records from a table where the exact id is present in the comma separated string above.

here is how I am doing it

```
Select id from absence where charIndex(cast(id as varchar), '2461519,2461520,2461521') > 0
```

The expected result is

```
2461519
2461520
2461521
```

But, the query above also picked

```
2461519
2461520
2461521
461519
461520
461521
246151
246152
246152
```

How do I modify this to get the ones that are only exact matches.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  For SQL Server 2016+ (and a corresponding db comptability level) this can be done pretty easily with [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: charindex() is giving you a False-Positive.

Comment: @squillman sql server 11.0.7 is the version

Comment: How are you building the query? Can't you just build `id IN (2461519,2461520,2461521)`?

Comment: @MatBailie I get the input as a comma separated string to my stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate a comma to the beginning and end of the id list and the lookup value which forces `CHARINDEX` to match on an id encapsulated by commas, ensuring it won't return a partial match.

```
Select id
FROM absence
WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)), ','), CONCAT(',','2461519,2461520,2461521', ',')) > 0;
```

Here's a working example:

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(100) = '2461519,2461520,2461521';
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT);
INSERT @t (id)
VALUES (2461519),(2461520),(2461521),(461519),(461520),
       (461521),(246151),(246152),(246152), (461), (519),
       (520), (24615);

Select id
FROM @t absence
WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)), ','), CONCAT(',', @ids, ',')) > 0;
```

Here is a solution using `string_split` for SQL Server 2016 and newer:

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(100) = '2461519,2461520,2461521';
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT);
INSERT @t (id)
VALUES (2461519),(2461520),(2461521),(461519),(461520),
       (461521),(246151),(246152),(246152), (461), (519),
       (520), (24615);

SELECT absencse.id
FROM @t absencse
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@ids, ',') ss ON absencse.id = ss.value;
```